# How to create a token using jquery with django passing variable to the front?

Tags: jquery, python, django, token

Front end and back end are in two different servers,they are able to connect now but without using django's own template to get the user's info.

How can I use jQuery to get user's info?

Let's say after a user log in, django does pass an object named `user` into front end.
But how can i use jquery to get it and save it as token so info does save for a period of time?

I am using ajax to connect to the backend

```
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url    : "api",
    data   : {
        email   : email,
        password: password
    },
    success: function (data) {
        clearInputs();
        error(data.message);
        successRedirect(data);
    },
    error  : function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that django renders templates in serverside, for this reason you can not access to the objects, however, if you need any information from the bacenkd, maybe you can render in your template some as follow (ie using a div, you can use any element that you consider necessary)

`<div id="username-{{request.user}}"></div`

Django will be render your template and it'll create a div with id `username-this-is-a-logged-username`

or in JS for example

`var logged_user_id = '{{request.user.id}}'`

in your case, if you are using ajax you can add neccessary info to the response in your view,

ie, in your view

```
def some_view(request):
    response = {
       "user": request.user.username,
       "user_id": request.user.id,
    }
    # some view actions

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

and now in your JS you can access to your data

```
        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url    : "api",
            data   : {
                email   : email,
                password: password
            },
            success: function (data) {
                clearInputs();

                // here you can access to the fields that you have defined in your view
                console.log(data["username"]);
                console.log(data["user_id"]);
            },
            error  : function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
```

`some_view` should be the view that answers to `api` url

Comment: but this is using the django build in template rendering which my project isn't using.  So for front end, it's not using any of django's build in template.  It's totally separate.

Comment: Well, can you explain, better,  paste a code where shows how you connect front and back end?

Comment: Thanks @Tsuna, altought you had to edit your question, not my answer, but i already have edited it